# Unable to send value through Ajax in Codeigniter 4.1.3

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-4

I am using CodeIgniter 4.1.3 for a project. I am facing issue caching value in Controller through Ajax post. Codes are following:

```
$(document).on('click','#showCont', function(){
        var memID=$(this).attr('data-mem');
        $data = {memID: memID};
        //console.log($data);
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?=base_url();?>"+"/Member/getContact/",
            headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
            type: "POST",        
            data: $data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (cont) {
                console.log(cont);
            }       
        });
    });
```

And here is the Controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;

use App\Models\Project_model;
use App\Models\General_model;
use CodeIgniter\I18n\Time;

class Member extends BaseController {
    public function getContact(){
      if ($this->request->isAJAX()) {
          // echo "Hi"; printing Hi in console
          //echo $query = $this->request->getPost('memID'); // returning nothing
          print_r($_REQUEST);
      }
}
```

And the route:

```
$routes->post('Member/getContact)', 'Member::getContact');
```

Below is the response of print_r in console.log

```
Array
(
    [__tawkuuid] => e::xxxdomainxxx.com::FtBr5/am9LXZ8gvI7KxyHJZ279zLJEw11KZhdGh+4sflsIqrslML4R2NgRYqN8Vc::2
    [__utmz] => 120264590.1625144765.12.5.utmcsr=l.facebook.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/
    [_ga] => GA1.2.2142405146.1621409499
    [__utmc] => 120264590
    [__utma] => 120264590.2142405146.1621409499.1629910859.1629978516.31
    [_gid] => GA1.2.1913990981.1630182229
    [ci_session] => e27a1e9ce4d0ee37f9b6569bd8eb15ab77fe45b2
)
```

Unable to understand why print_r $_INPUT is not showing sent data. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing the ajax correctly, you are going to have to pass the parameter in the url

```
$(document).on('click','#showCont', function(){
        var memID=$(this).attr('data-mem');
        $data = {memID: memID};
        //console.log($data);
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?=base_url();?>"+"/Member/getContact/" + "<?=$data?>",
            headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
            type: "GET",        
            cache: false,
            success: function (cont) {
                console.log(cont);
            }       
        });
    });
```

On the other hand if you are using codeigniter 4 csrf validation, the method cannot be POST, you will have to use GET.